# addEventListener method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am building simple counter application and in Javascript `addEventListern`is not working
giving this error:

[image: error in chrome developer tool]

Here is my JavaScript Code which i tried but it still gives error of

> Cannot read property 'addEventLister' of Null

```js
//selecting elements
let value = document.getElementById('value');
let counter = 0;
value.textContent = counter;
// addingEventListener
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
document.getElementById('increase').addEventListener('click', increase);
document.getElementById('decrease').addEventListener('click', decrease);
// Event functions

function reset() {
  counter = 0;
}

function increase() {
  counter++;
}

function decrease() {
  counter--;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="two-times">Counter</p>
      <p class="two-times" id="value">0</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input class="btn" id="decrease" type="button" value="Recrease">
        <input class="btn" id="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
        <input class="btn" id="Increase" type="button" value="Increase">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- javaScript -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('increase').addEventListener('click', increase);
```

And

```js
<input class="btn" id="Increase" type="button" value="Increase">
```

Don't match

```js
//selecting elements
let value = document.getElementById('value');
let counter = 0;
value.textContent = counter;
// addingEventListener
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
document.getElementById('Increase').addEventListener('click', increase);
document.getElementById('decrease').addEventListener('click', decrease);
// Event functions

function reset() {
  counter = 0;
}

function increase() {
  counter++;
}

function decrease() {
  counter--;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="two-times">Counter</p>
      <p class="two-times" id="value">0</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input class="btn" id="decrease" type="button" value="Recrease">
        <input class="btn" id="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
        <input class="btn" id="Increase" type="button" value="Increase">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- javaScript -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. The input element has an ID with uppercase (Increase) and you are trying to access it with the lowercase name (increase).